# Visual Studio Work Item Preview

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2017

In VS 2017 with TFS, I used to be able to go to my list of bug and click on one, and it would show in the lower half of the screen (I could double click and it would open in another tab). But that has suddenly stopped working since we just upgraded TFS.

I can restore the *open in a tab* function under Tools -> Options -> Work Items -> Open work items in and then select "Visual Studio (compatibility mode)", but I can restore the ability to see the ticket in the lower half of the same bug list like I had before.

Is there any way to restore this functionality? For one particular project it is really important to have the bugs and the solution in the same place. Switching back and forth from a browser and VS is really inconvenient.

Comment: What's detail version of your original TFS and the upgraded  TFS? Are you using the  new work item form in TFS2017?  Better to add a previous screenshot for reference.

Answer (score 1):

According to your description, most likely you are using the [new work item form](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/work/customize/process/new-work-item-experience) which released since TFS2017.

If you use the new work item tracking with Visual Studio 2017, you may have noticed **that work items now open in a browser window** by default. This change to how you interact with work items allows us to provide you with a number of benefits. Details please refer：[Work items now open in the web from Visual Studio ’15’](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/devops/2016/08/22/work-items-now-open-in-the-web-from-visual-studio-15/)

You could also  set your preferred way of opening work items using the settings available at *Tools -> Options -> Work Items-> Visual Studio (compatibility mode)* as you have done. However that's not a recommend way, and you may get the different output either the worktiem fields or the window like you had before.

> For example, new work item customization options such as checkbox
>   features, as well as the new work item form layouts that were
>   introduced in Visual Studio Team Services may not be available in the
>   work item controls available in the current release of Visual Studio's
>   Controls library.
>
> To **ensure compatibility with the new process customization
>   capabilities**, new controls and the new Work item form options, just
>   you keep Visual Studio  open work items in the browser.

If you insist on using the previews way, you could try to [switch back to the old form](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/work/customize/process/new-work-item-experience#switch-back-to-the-old-form) once your admin has enabled opt-in to support switch back. Then check if the layout in Visual Studio also restored back.

Comment: Ok thanks for the info. But that really sucks for at least one solution I have which has a whole bunch of projects that requires me to jump from bugs to solution explorer and back all the time. That workflow is now completely borked. Removing choices is never a good move.